EventUuid is missing in platform event data received in LWC using emp-api
I am working on a platform event that is subscribed in LWC using lightning/empApi. I am getting all the data as expected but the EventUuid field is constantly missing. I have tried with multiple standard events as well but all of them are behaving the same only.
Found a GitHub issue on the same but the reply indicates it's not with the LWC framework, but rather something specific to empApi.
Is there any specific reason? Or anyone have any idea how to receive it?
Here is a sample event data received in LWC:
{
  "data": {
    "schema": "2Y1NzOdw.......",
    "payload": {
      "ExceptionType": "System.MathException",
      "JobScope": "a07IR......,a07IR......",
      "Phase": "EXECUTE",
      "CreatedById": "005I......",
      "Message": "Divide by 0",
      "RequestId": "5-wn......",
      "StackTrace": "Class.PEDemoBatchFailure.execute: line 26, column 1",
      "CreatedDate": "2024-12-08T12:33:39Z",
      "AsyncApexJobId": "707IR.....",
      "DoesExceedJobScopeMaxLength": false
    },
    "event": {
      "replayId": 1
    }
  },
  "channel": "/event/BatchApexErrorEvent"
}


Could be an API version issue or the way you're creating the event
